# Why is it recommended to not(!) display error details at UWP app crashes?

Tags: error-handling, uwp

According to [Exception handling for Windows Runtime apps in C# or Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn532194) MS recommends:

*"If your app crashes, don't attempt to display any info to the user that describes the specifics of the crash even if the app lifetime state lets you do so."*

[This recommendation is for WinRT apps, there seems to be not recommendation for UWP. I assume we are supposed to treat them the same.]

Can someone explain the rationale behind this?

The MS UWP apps do follow this rule. I have had Mail, Translator, Calculator, the Store app, ... abort without any feedback on crash or at restart.

I personally find it annoying when apps simply disappear without any hint.
The "little Watson" solution of displaying error info on the next start feels weird to me. Both behaviors doe not conform with common user expectations

What is wrong with in App_UnhandledException:

- display a MessageDialog with error details,
- and then rethrow the exception to force the app to crash?

Rare cases where the app is in such a bad state that it cannot display a MessageDialog (which I have never experienced) are no reason not to try.

I understand that in App_UnhandledException the app might be in a undefined/fragile state and one should minimize the code executed here. But we do already trace exceptions here and track them via HockeyApp. Why not notify the user?

If crash error notifications are helpful for users depends on the app and the target audience. For enterprise apps I know from long experience that error notifications (even with deep technical infos) are definitely helpful. Users are often able to circumvent problems and keep working with defective apps without even contacting support (while support was automatically made aware of the problem). The value for consumer oriented apps is debatable. I assume many users will stop entering 0 as a divisor when seeing an Arg_OverflowException right after entering data or remember having unplugged their cable modem when seeing a http_client exception.

Comment: The error message isn't useful to a user. *"This application crashed, because ..."* The user doesn't care. They aren't going to take any actions based on the message. They will start the app again, regardless of whether there was a message or not. If you need the information for diagnostics, have your app write a minidump.

Comment: This is a valid aspect. I updated my question commenting this.

Comment: The update assumes, that you **can** come up with helpful error messages. Your example (`Arg_OverflowException` when entering 0 as a divisor) would often lead to users shaking their heads, followed by *"Meh, M$ sucks"*. If it were along the lines of "division by zero", that would be a different story. But that just shows how hard it is to deduce **helpful** error messages from exception records. If you want your app to be helpful, don't let it run into an unhandled exception handler. Instead, handle the http_client exception, and let the user know to turn on their cable modem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No technical reasons against notifying users about unexpected exceptions at UWP app crashes or showing exception details were stated. If such notifications may be helpful for end users depends on the app and the target audience.

Here a code sample notifying the user from within App.UnhandledExcetion or at next app start:

```
Protected Overrides Async Sub OnLaunched(e As Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.LaunchActivatedEventArgs)
  ...
    If _notifyUserAboutCrash = NotifyUserAboutCrash.OnNextStart Then
        Await ProblemReporter.NotifyLastExToUserIfExisting()
    End If
  ...
End Sub

Private Async Sub App_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
    If _isAborting Then Return
    Dim unhandledEx = New Exception(e.Message, e.Exception)

    e.Handled = True

    Trace.Error($"Unexpected exception: {unhandledEx.InnerException.ToString}")
    Await Trace.CompleteAsync()
    Try
        ProblemReporter.SaveAsLastException(unhandledEx)
        HockeyClient.Current.TrackException(unhandledEx.InnerException)
        HockeyClient.Current.Flush()
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        Trace.Error(ex)
    End Try

    If _notifyUserAboutCrash = NotifyUserAboutCrash.OnError Then
        Await ProblemReporter.NotifyExceptionToUserViaMessageDialogAsync(unhandledEx)
    End If

    Await ForceAppCrashAsync(unhandledEx)
End Sub

Private Shared Async Function ForceAppCrashAsync(unhandledEx As Exception) As Task
    Trace.Fatal("!!! aborting")
    Await Trace.CompleteAsync()
    _isAborting = True
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(unhandledEx.InnerException).Throw()
End Function
```

For the complete code and some gotchas see my post [Global Error Handling for UWP-Apps](https://petermeinl.wordpress.com/2016/07/09/global-error-handling-for-uwp-apps/).